# JavaFX: coding item-template / cell-factory in fxml?

Tags: java, javafx, cell, fxml

Is it possible to directly code cell-factory in FXML? I'm hoping to achieve something like:

```
<GridPane fx:itemType="MyBookmarkClass">
    <children>
        <Label GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" text="${name}"/>
        <Label GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" text="${link}"/>
        <ImageView>
            <image>
                <Image url="${favoicon}" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

and create/bind it with each item in the observableList given as source to ComboBox and ListView etc, instead of doing all cell factory in java code like what I'm doing now.

I'm only a few days into JavaFX and not really sure what's the recommended/correct way of doing it? Maybe I could create a stub cell factory, calling FXMLLoader and set item as the controller?

PS: My final goal is to make the application like what I did in WPF, using only XAML describing UI blocks and data templates, plus the model code, which not POCO but modified to be directly bindable to XAML, plus a set of expression converters doing logical operations and string functions etc, to reduce the need of UI manipulation in code-behind.